# How to submit a form using codeigniter without changing the url?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm Unable to submit the form within the same page and getting result in the same page.

Comment: Show the code you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Put in the action of the your form the current URL.

`action="<?php echo current_url();?>"`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need

```
redirect('controllerName')
```

So once you send data from the form to the controller, that controller does the processing and then redirects back to the index().

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax and Javascript to submit form without changing the url.